# C# ComboBox Select Error: "Incorrect Syntax Near '.'"

Tags: c#, combobox

**Note:** my office doesn't allow me to view YouTube and several other sites that probably have the answer to this question on them (they are blocked), which is why Googling the answer hasn't yielded results.

ComboBox code reference: [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/9387c998-3373-4d58-85dc-87bb9234e108/)

On my `C# Form`, I have filled a ComboBox with tables from a database (see below code), which returns the appropriate values and functions correctly:

```
public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "CONNECTION STRING" // shortened for security and convenience

        // Fill ComboBox with SQL Values
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmbTables = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM sys.tables", conn);
        SqlDataReader read = cmbTables.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable cmbData = new DataTable();
        cmbData.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        cmbData.Load(read);
        cmb1.DisplayMember = "name";
        cmb1.DataSource = cmbData;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

After the `ComboBox` loads the tables (which works), the application then selects a table and clicks a button that loads the table, which is selected.  This is where the code errors:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var connection = Utilities.GetConnection())
            { 

                string table = Convert.ToString(txt1.Text);
                string cmb1Value = Convert.ToString(cmb1.SelectedItem);

                // Stored Procedure
                SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE STOREDPROCEDURE" + cmb1Value, connection); // shortened for security and convenience
                select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(cmb1Value, table));

                // Data View
                SqlDataAdapter ad= new SqlDataAdapter(select);
                ad.SelectCommand = select;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dt); // this generates the error "Incorrect Syntax Near '.'"
                BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
                b.DataSource = dt;
                dGrid.DataSource = b;
                ad.Update(dt);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Even though the ComboBox loads the appropriate values, from the above code, I may be missing something which attaches those values to the `SELECT` stored procedure (all it does is call `SELECT` statement through a variable passed to it).  The error, `"Incorrect Syntax Near '.'"` looks like a `SQL Server` error that I've seen, but can't remember how I generate it (this is how I usually troubeshoot where the `TSQL` code went wrong).\

Stored Procedure Related code:

```
C#:    
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE STOREDPROCEDURE " + cmb1Value, connection);

TSQL:    

CREATE PROCEDURE [STOREDPROCEDURE]
    @TableName VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM ' + @TableName

    EXECUTE(@sql)

END

-- Note this works in SSMS without a problem.
```

The above code is incorrect, and when I tweak the `TSQL` code, I generate similar errors, telling me that somewhere I am missing a conversion, or another variable because `SQL Server` isn't seeing these table values returned by the `SELECT` (first block of code).  I can ascertain this because I have a second ComboBox that uses similar code **EXCEPT** that I populated the ComboBox with manual values, and it connects to the tables in the database with no error.  So, the ComboBox, which grabs values from the database, that you see above, does not function correctly.

For instance, if I only add the below line of code to the code, I receive an error that it can't find the database "EXECUTE STOREDPROCEDURE System'

```
select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

However, `System` isn't a part of anything, so where did that come from?  It never errored with this code on the manual ComboBox, as it had no trouble finding the database (using the same connection string, server and database!).

If I try to use a TSQL parameter, such as:

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE stp_ReturnTable @p", scon);
select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p", cmb1Value));
```

Suddenly, it can't find the stored procedure.  Again, the connection strings are identical for the manual ComboBox and the dynamic ComboBox.

I think the code behind the dynamic ComboBox is wrong.  When I'm out of the office, I'll review some videos with detailed demonstrations on how to create a dynamic ComboBox from a database and I have a hunch that a system object is in the way (based on the System error, which exists nowhere in my code, as well as it suddenly being unable to find the database or procedure).

Comment: is your connection string actually "CONNECTION STRING"?

Comment: @a_schimpf No, thanks for asking.  CONNECTION STRING and STOREDPROCEDURE are actual names that I shortened for convenience and security.

Comment: is there a whitespace missing between EXECUTE STOREDPROCEDURE" + cmb1Value ?

Comment: @StefanoL Yes, it's EXECUTE STOREDPROCEDURE " + cmb1Value

Comment: Even though you're using a parameter, this code is vulnerable to sql injection since you are using string concatenation in the SP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing key point in your code is the [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx).
Without the proper set of this property the default is CommandText and thus the Framework expects  a statement that starts with SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc....

```
using (var connection = Utilities.GetConnection())
{ 
    string table = Convert.ToString(txt1.Text);
    string cmb1Value = Convert.ToString(cmb1.SelectedItem);

    // Stored Procedure
    SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("STOREDPROCEDURE", connection);
    select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableName", cmb1Value));


    // That's the key to let ADO.NET accept the previous CommandText as valid.
    // If you omit this the CommandText is assumed to be a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE etc..
    select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  


    // Data View
    SqlDataAdapter ad= new SqlDataAdapter(select);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt); 
    BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
    b.DataSource = dt;
    dGrid.DataSource = b;
}
```

**EDIT** Having seen the code of the SP then you could simply set the SqlParameter name to the constant `@TableName` and pass the value extracted from the combobox as the value to be used inside the SP

**EDIT** I have looked again at your code and I suspect that the culprit is the line

```
 string cmb1Value = Convert.ToString(cmb1.SelectedItem);
```

Looking at how you have filled your combo, this line, doesn't return the tablename as you expect, but the generic string `System.Data.DataRowView` because the DataSource of the combo is a DataTable and not a string collection. You should try to change that line in this way

```
DataRowView rw = cmb1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
if(rw != null)
{
     string cmbValue1 = rw["name"].ToString();
     ....
```

And yes, your code should work also without the `CommandType.StoredProcedure` line because the text `EXECUTE sp param` is recognized as a valid sql commandtext (but why do you use it when a direct call to the storedprocedure could be optimized for reuse?)

Comment: Thanks on your final edit.  I'm not available to test that, but I will later on and I suspect you're right, so I'll mark you as the answer when I test.  Again, thanks for the work (would give you +2 if I could).

Comment: Well, let's hope that this is the problem then. See you again on SO